# Route not defined laravel 5.2 error

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am building a login page for the user in which one can sign up by filling the sign up form or can login with facebook.

Login with facebook is working fine and is routing to the user's profile page whereas when one logins after registering on the site ,error occurs stating that "route[myplace] not defined which is working in case of login with facebook.

My routes.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 })->name('home');


Route::post('/signup' , [

                'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp' ,
                'as' => 'signup' 
    ]);

Route::post('/signin' , [

                'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn' ,
                'as' => 'signin' 
    ]);


Route::get('/myplace' , [

        'uses' => 'UserController@getmyplace' ,

        'as' => 'myplace' ,

        'middleware' => 'auth:web'

])->name('myplace');

Route::get('/verify' , [ 


                'uses' => 'UserController@getverify' ,
                'as' => 'verify' 


    ]);

 Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToFacebook');
 Route::get('login/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@getFacebookCallback');
```

my postSignIn function in UserController.php:

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[

            'email'=> 'required' ,
            'password' => 'required'

            ]);


    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))
    {
        return redirect()->route('myplace');
    }

        return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,I was using same route for different controllers.So ,i just copied my myplace function from UserController.php to AuthController.php and it worked.